# Extract image src and make it the src of another image

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie and i just couldn't find any solution through google.
This is a very simple code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function image() {
        var imgSource = document.getElementById('myImage').src;
    }
</script>

<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
 <img id="myImage" src="../logo.JPG" />
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <img src="**SRC FROM IMAGE 1**" />
</div>
```

Basically what I want to do is to get src of image in the first div and put it in the image src in the second div.

Please help.

Comment: How do you call your `image()` function?

Comment: And how do you identify the targetted `<img>`?

Comment: you don't have any code to actually **USE** this `imgSource` variable, or even call the `image()` function... but if you can figure out how to get a `src`, then CHANGING a `src` isn't very different...

Comment: What Marc B is referring to is that you can do something like this: `document.getElementById('myImage2').src = document.getElementById('myImage').src;`

Answer (score 0):

Put the script at the bottom of the body when you are accessing its content. This way its sure that when the script executes the upper part has already loaded.
Secondly you have to call the function  to get executed.

```
 <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
 <img id="myImage" src="../logo.JPG" /> </div>


 <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
 <img src="**SRC FROM IMAGE 1**" id="anotherImage" />
 </div> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function image() {
    var imgSource = document.getElementById('myImage').src;
    document.getElementById('anotherImage').src=imgSource;
  } 
  image();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your destination img tag had an id="destination".  Then you could easily accomplish what you are trying to do by just doing something like this:

So what you could do is change your script tag to this (and maybe move it below both divs in the html):

```
function image() {
    var imgSource = document.getElementById('myImage').src;
    document.getElementById('destination').src = imgSource;
};
image();
```